# Python 3.8 - Selenium: generated random number inside xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How do I do retrieve the generated number inside the xpath ... in the NEEDED HERE position?
randomNumber = random.randint(1, 3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[NEEDED HERE}]/a/span").click()

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `"/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div" + str(randomNumber) + "/a/span` in the

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```